# HSSF changing column width

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a project that writes to an excel file. I am using the HSSF POI. My code works fine as far as writing to the excel file however I am having a problem regarding formatting. I want to make the each column a specific width. I did the research for this and am certain that I am following exactly what was described however the cell does not change at runtime. Below is my code:

Test Class

```
package mainClass;

import parsing.WriteExcel;

public class TestClass 

{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        WriteExcel wExcel = new WriteExcel();
        wExcel.writeExcel();

    }

}
```

Write Class

```
package parsing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.scene.control.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class WriteExcel 

{

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\jhamric\\Documents\\PainDifferences.xls";

    public void writeExcel(){

        ArrayList<String> sample1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> sample2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        sample1.add("1");
        sample1.add("2");
        sample2.add("a");
        sample2.add("b");

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Unmatched Transactions");

        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 25);

        HSSFFont fontBold = workbook.createFont();
        fontBold.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        HSSFCellStyle styleBold = workbook.createCellStyle();
        styleBold.setFont(fontBold);

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

        data.put("0",new Object[]{"Number","Letter"});

        //for(int i = 0; i < ParseFiles.InstrId.size(); i++){

        for(int i = 0; i < sample1.size(); i++){

            String currentIString = Integer.toString(i+1);

            data.put(currentIString, new Object[]{sample1.get(i),sample2.get(i)});

            //data.put(currentIString, new Object[]{ParseFiles.InstrId.get(i)});

        }

        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for(String key: keyset){
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for(Object obj : objArr){
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if(cell.toString().equals("Number")){
                cell.setCellStyle(styleBold);
            }
            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);

            }
        }




        try{

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_PATH));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            workbook.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Specifically I declare the code to set the column width here:

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 25);
```

My understanding is that the first number is the index (so it would actually be the 2nd column) and the second number is the character length, so all cells in the column should be 25 characters long of whitespace.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The value is actually not the number of characters but something else. I tried 5000 and it correctly resized the column.

Comment: ...but something else: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29

Comment: @Richter The math on that link does not really add up, but 1/256th of an inch does.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is that `Sheet.setColumnWidth(int index, int width)` sets the column with for the column to width*256. You are correct in your assertion that index is zero based column number. The width is specified in 1/256 of a character.

Comment: Not just any character though, as [explained in the Javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29) it's effectively the width of the number `0`

Answer (score 0):

to set the width as 25 characters you need to pass (1,25 * 256)